# Silverlight HyperlinkButton NOT Working at ALL

Tags: silverlight, button, hyperlink

I'm trying to implement the Siverlight HyperlinkButton according to [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.hyperlinkbutton%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="Click here to learn about Silverlight"
                 NavigateUri="http://www.silverlight.net" 
                 TargetName="_blank" 
                 Margin="10,60,0,0"/>
```

But, when I build and click it, it shows nothing.

Comment: Have you enabled navigation as described in the remarks? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833071(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Yes, I added, but still the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that you have not enabled external navigation for the Silverlight object. If you haven't a security exception will be getting thrown when you click the link, but you may be catching it without knowing. This is described in the remarks section of your above link.

To enable navigation edit your Silveright host page (E.G. index.html) and add the following param under the Silverlight object

```
<param name="enableNavigation" value="true" />
```

By default Silverlight generates the .html page each time you run/debug so you will lose the param. To get around this make a copy of the .html file in the same directory but with a different name or manually specify which .html file to use in the project settings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833071(v=vs.95).aspx

Update:

This works for Chrome, Firefox and IE8. It does not work for IE9. You can test this in IE by using the developer tools. Links work with Document Mode IE8 but throw an Unauthorized Access exception when using Document Mode IE9.

Update #2:

To get it to work in IE9 you can force it to use the IE8 Document Mode. To do this you need to remove the DOCTYPE tag and add a meta tag. E.G.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8">
    .
    .
```

Instead of

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
  <head>
    .
    .
```

Comment: In your App.xaml.cs can you set a breakpoint in Application_UnhandledException and see if an exception is being thrown when you click the link?

Comment: `ExceptionObject: {System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.`  Is it a cross-domain issue?

Comment: I can reproduce that error. Adding the above param fixes it for me. You need to be careful though. Every time you build or debug your application it replaces your modified .html file with the normal one. Make a copy of the .html file with a different name in the same directory, add the parameter in the new file and launch your Silverlight app by opening that new .html file and see how it goes

Comment: Yes, I'm using a specific test page.  And I verified it by checking the html source code when I run it.

Comment: Hmm. I've just noticed that for me links work in Chrome but fails in IE. Looking at why now

Comment: Hmmm, if we disable the IE9 document mode, I'm afraid if we will have any other side effects?

Comment: Silverlight itself will behave fine. The only reason you would need to be concerned would be if you were using a more complicated .html page to host your Silverlight control

Answer (score 0):

You Should Visit This Link For Hyperlink Button Issue or ..... it's defiantly working.....

```
<UserControl x:Class="HyperlinkButton2.Page"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Width="300" Height="100">
    <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <HyperlinkButton x:Name="hbtnTest" TargetName="_blank" Content="SilverlightShow" NavigateUri="http://www.silverlightshow.net" Canvas.Top="40" Canvas.Left="30"></HyperlinkButton>
    </Canvas>
```

[Using the HyperlinkButton control in Silverlight](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-HyperlinkButton-control-in-Silverlight-2-Beta-1.aspx)